# Stats for Koalinth in DnD 3.5 edition

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

Does anyone has any stats for Koalinth creature and for DnD 3.5 edition? Or, does anyone knows where I can find them?

Answer (score 2):

The koalinth (aquatic hobgoblins) were never officially statted for D&D 3.5e. There are unofficial conversions from places like dandwiki.com. which are questionably legal so I'm not going to link them, but even the lowest level of Google-fu would find it.

Comment: I found description of the race but not stats. So, if you have found any stats, please share the link.

Comment: @Xxxo As the answer says, there are no official stats, and the unofficial stats are on sites that engage in piracy, so we won't link them. Have you tried Google?

Comment: Yes, I did. OK. Thnx anyway :) 

I will search again